# How to know/decrypt a json string like this

Tags: ios, json, encryption

I'm trying to sniff an iPhone application and when I send a request below is the sample of output i'm getting :

Sample output : http://shrib.com/encrypted

I'm wondering if anyone could help me in finding what type of decryption I can use to decrypt the above sample. 
is there any way that I can decrypt this without password if it has!

Comment: If you could easily decrypt encrypted things, what would be the point of encryption in the first place? I'm sure the output of certain encryption algorithms have certain properties, but I imagine this is implicitly avoided when making a good algorithm. Either way, discovering some of these properties may be fine for a research paper, but it's way too broad for a [so] question.

Comment: Are you sure it's not simply Base64 encoded?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of patterns in the sample which indicates it is not using good encryption. Properly encrypted data can not be distinguish from random data. Perhaps ECB mode is being used and there is a lot of repetitive data or worse yet it uses a home-grown encryption scheme.

It does not seem to be just Base64 encoded encrypted data, if so we wold see "?" and "+" characters. Nor does it appear to be simple Base64 encoded.

If it is just poorly encrypted the attack is chosen text, that is give it text to encrypt that you know and have it encrypted. At a minimum you will be able to make some gains with this but not necessarily succeed.

I would bet that this is a home-made encryption and could be broken within reasonable time. There is just so much repetition.

In sone manner Base64 is being used.
The first 64 character are:

> Vm0wd2QyUXlVWGxWV0d4V1YwZDRWMVl3WkRSV01WbDNXa1JTVjAxV2JETlhhMUpU

which Base64 decode to:

> Vm0wd2QyUXlVWGxWV0d4V1YwZDRWMVl3WkRSV01WbDNXa1JT

Notice the similarity!